# youtube API get videos of a logged in user

Tags: youtube-api

I am very new to the youtube API integration and trying to fetch a list of videos uploaded by a user (logged in user) on youtube?

I am currently trying to go through the youtube's API documentation and I will update this thread once I find a path forward. For now, just want to check and see if anyone here has already done this? and if so, can you help me with fast track my effort by pointing me to some specific resources?